# What is a general good practice for configuring core-pool-size-factor and max-pool-size-factor settings?

Tags: akka

For example, if the CPU has four cores and eight core threads.

- Should I set the **core-pool-size-factor** setting all the way to 8?
- What's a good general size for **max-pool-size-factor** in relation to **core-pool-size-factor**?
- Are there any other settings the ones I mentioned are related to withing Akka config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

core-pool-size-factor of 1.0 will be 1.0 x number of logical processors available to the runtime.

max-pool-size-factor should be the same as core-pool-size-factor unless you have a bounded queue for the pool (ThreadPoolExecutor does not grow the pool unless the queue is bounded)

Comment: in akka document wrote `core-pool-size-factor = available processors * factor` what is _factor_ in this formula ?

Comment: It's a factor to multiply the resulting number by.